# Разница между датами Python

Tags: python-3.x, django

Подскажите как вычислить разницу во времени для такой задачи: нужно чтобы при обновлении страницы поста было видно что пост обновлен 5 мин назад, или час назад - вообще некоторое время назад. Так чтобы для пользователей ничего не ломалось если они находятся в разных часовых поясах.

```
class Post(GenericPage):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=SET_NULL)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=now, verbose_name='publication date')
    modified_date = AutoLastModifiedField()
    short_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    infografic = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/post/', null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/thumbnails/', null=True, blank=True)
    related_posts = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='published')
```

Comment: Stack Overflow использует UTC: `<span title="2018-08-21 13:05:05Z" class="relativetime">5 часов назад</span>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5 минут одинаковы в любом часовом поясе, вычисляй разницу на сервере, как время запроса - время публикации согласно серверному времени и уже ее передавай на страницу.

Например - время публикации поста (по серверу) - 16:45
Это соответствует 18:45 для часового пояса случайного юзера.

Время загрузки/обновления страницы - 17:00 по серверу
и 19:00 по часовому поясу юзера.

17:00 - 16:45 = 15 минут
19:00 - 18:45 = 15 минут

Т.Е. в контексте этой задачи можно абстрагироваться от пользователя

Comment: Хорошая идея. Спасибо, все работает.

Comment: часовой пояс может и поменяться за 15 минут, поэтому локальное время без привязки к конкретной часовой зоне плохо вычитать (всё равно, что из километров мили пытаться вычитать -- результат бессмысленный). Следует timezone-aware datetime объекты использовать (django позволяет настроить)

Answer (score 0):

В django для этого уже есть готовая библиотека `django.contrib.humanize`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime

Можно поключать прямо в шаблонах:

```
{% load humanize %}

<div>{{ item.date|naturaltime }}</div>
```

Например, (если ‘now’ - 17 Фев 2007 16:30:00):

17 Фев 2007 16:30:00 станет - *сейчас*.

17 Фев 2007 16:29:31 будет - *29 секунд назад*.

и т.д.